# How can I speed up my code coverage tool?

Tags: winapi, testing, x86, code-coverage

I've written a small code coverage utility to log which basic blocks are hit in an x86 executable. It runs without source code or debugging symbols for the target, and just takes a lost of basic blocks which it monitors.

However, it is becoming the bottleneck in my application, which involves repeated coverage snapshots of a single executable image.

It has gone through a couple of phases as I've tried to speed it up. I started off just placing an INT3 at the start of each basic block, attaching as debugger, and logging hits. Then I tried to improve performance by patching in a counter to any block bigger than 5 bytes (the size of a JMP REL32). I wrote a small stub ('mov [blah], 1 / jmp backToTheBasicBlockWeCameFrom') in the process memory space and patch a JMP to that. This greatly speeds things up, since there's no exception and no debugger break, but I'd like to speed things up more.

I'm thinking of one of the following:

1) Pre-instrument the target binary with my patched counters (at the moment I do this at runtime). I could make a new section in the PE, throw my counters in it, patch in all the hooks I need, then just read data out of the same section with my debugger after each execution. That'll gain me some speed (about a 16% according to my estimation) but there are still those pesky INT3's which I need to have in the smaller blocks, which are really going to cripple performance.

2) Instrument the binary to include its own UnhandledExceptionFilter and handle its own int3's in conjunction with the above. This would mean there's no process switch from the debuggee to my coverage tool on every int3, but there'd still be the breakpoint exception raised and the subsequent kernel transition - am I right in thinking this wouldn't actually gain me much performance?

3) Try to do something clever using Intel's hardware branch profiling instructions. This sounds pretty awesome but I'm not clear on how I'd go about it - is it even possible in a windows usermode application? I might go as far as to write a kernel-mode driver if it's fairly straightforward but I'm not a kernel coder (I dabble a bit) and would probably cause myself lots of headaches. Are there any other projects using this approach? I see the Linux kernel has it to monitor the kernel itself, which makes me think that monitoring a specific usermode application will be difficult.

4) Use an off-the-shelf application. It'd need to work without any source or debugging symbols, be scriptable (so I can run in batches), and preferably be free (I'm pretty stingy). For-pay tools aren't off the table, however (if I can spend less on a tool and increase perf enough to avoid buying new hardware, that'd be good justification).

5) Something else. I'm running in VMWare on Windows XP, on fairly old hardware (Pentium 4-ish) - is there anything I've missed, or any leads I should read up on? Can I get my JMP REL32 down to less than 5 bytes (and catch smaller blocks without the need for an int3)?

Thanks.

Comment: Vote-to-close as "not-constructive"?   It amazes me how many SO folks vote to close perfectly legitimate questions, with perfectly reasonable answers.   You guys give SO a bad flavor.

Comment: I'm curious.  If you're doing this without source or symbols, how are you examining the results?  Are you simply computing a percent covered value?  If the percent is low, how do you figure out which sections your tests are missing?

Comment: I'm actually doing black-box fuzzing to find security holes. The idea is that I mutate an input file slightly, observe any new blocks that are opened up, and then 'descend' in to mutating that input more if it opens up blocks we haven't seen before. (If you've got an hour or so to spare, I found Travis Ormandy's presentation "making software dumber" fascinating - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqZRuvdbR64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on instrumenting binaries, pretty much your fastest coverage is the 5-byte jump-out jump-back  trick.  (You're covering standard ground for binary instrumentation tools.)

The INT 3 solution will always involve a trap. Yes, you could handle the trap in your space instead of a debugger space and that would speed up it, but it will never be close to competitive to the jump-out/back patch.    You may need it as backup anyway, if the function you are instrumenting happens to be shorter than 5 bytes (e.g., "inc eax/ret") because then you don't have 5 bytes you can patch.

What you might do to optimize things a little is examine the patched code.  Without such examination, with original code:

```
         instrn 1
         instrn 2
         instrn N
  next:
```

patched, in general to look like this:

```
         jmp patch
         xxx 
  next:
```

has to generally have a patch:

```
   patch: pushf
          inc   count
          popf
          instrn1
          instrn2
          instrnN
          jmp   back
```

If all you want is *coverage*, you don't need to increment, and the means you don't need to save the flags:

```
   patch: mov    byte ptr covered,1
          instrn1
          instrn2
          instrnN
          jmp   back
```

You should use a *byte* rather than a word to keep the patch size down.  You should align the patch on a cache line so the processor doesn't have fetch 2 cache lines to execute the patch.

If you insist on counting, you can analyze the instrn1/2/N to see if they care about the flags that "inc" fools with, and only pushf/popf if needed, or you can insert the increment between two instructions in the patch that don't care.  You must be analyzing these to some extent to handle complications such as instn being **ret** anyway; you can generate a better patch (e.g., don't "jmp back").

You may find that using **add count,1** is faster than **inc count** because this avoids partial condition code updates and consequent pipeline interlocks.  This will affect your cc-impact-analysis a bit, since **inc** doesn't set the carry bit, and **add** does.

Another possibility is PC sampling. Don't instrument the code at all; just interrupt the thread periodically and take a sample PC value.   If you know where the basic blocks are, a PC sample anywhere in the basic block is evidence the entire block got executed.  This won't necessarily give precise coverage data (you may miss critical PC values), but the overhead is pretty low.

If you are willing to patch *source* code, you can do better: just insert "covered[i]=true;" in the beginning the ith basic block, and let the compiler take care of all the various optimizations.   No patches needed.  The really cool part of this is that if you have basic blocks *inside* nested loops, and you insert source probes like this, the compiler will notice that the probe assignments are idempotent with respect to the loop and lift the probe out of the loop.  Viola, zero probe overhead inside the loop.  What more more could you want?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers (heeh). At the moment I use a 'mov byte ptr, 1' in my stubs, but I didn't think of aligning on a cache line at all..

Comment: Looks like this is the best answer I'm going to get. I'm accepting it as an Answer mostly because it's full of useful info, even if some of it doesn't apply to my scenario (eg, I don't need to count, no source, etc).